# How might I have Webforms save files to private file system or as a database blob?

Tags: 7, hooks, webforms, files

In Drupal 7, I have the file system configured as

[image]

In the code for the Webforms' file component located at `sites/all/modules/webform/components/file.inc`, it appears that one could easily change it so that Webform file uploads are moved to the private file system by `changing 'scheme' => 'public'` to `'scheme' => 'private'`. But I also know the pitfalls of hacking (changing) anything that could easily be overwritten with `drush upc`.

```
 /**
 * Implements _webform_defaults_component().
 */
function _webform_defaults_file() {
  return array(
    'name' => '',
    'form_key' => NULL,
    'required' => 0,
    'pid' => 0,
    'weight' => 0,
    'extra' => array(
      'filtering' => array(
        'types' => array('gif', 'jpg', 'png'),
        'addextensions' => '',
        'size' => '2 MB',
      ),
      'scheme' => 'public',
      'directory' => '',
      'progress_indicator' => 'throbber',
      'title_display' => 0,
      'description' => '',
      'attributes' => array(),
      'private' => FALSE,
      'analysis' => FALSE,
    ),
  );
}
```

Given that all file uploads are stored referenced in the file_managed table

```
mysql> describe file_managed;
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| fid       | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uid       | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| filename  | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |         |                |
| uri       | varchar(255)        | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| filemime  | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |         |                |
| filesize  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| status    | tinyint(4)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| timestamp | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Is it feasible to do a post operation to a file upload that manually moves a file from public:// to private:// *and* updates the database entry? Would [hook_file_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_file_presave/7) or [hook_file_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_file_insert/7) be good tools to accomplish this?**

### Update

Based on the suggestion of using hook_webform_component_info_alter(), I implemented the following

```
/**
 * Implements hook_webform_component_info_alter().
 */
function  MYMOD_webform_component_info_alter(&$components) {
   $components['file']['extra']['scheme'] = 'private';
   dsm($components['file']);
}


/**
 * Implements hook_file_insert().
 */
function MYMOD_file_insert($file) {
  dsm($file);
}
```

After the output of the DSM() shows the component array seems to be altered but the DSM from hook_file_insert() still shows that the file was deposited into the public area:

[image]

Comment: I'm just guessing, I haven't looked into this situation all that much but I see in the code from Webform under the extra array there is a 'private' => FALSE, can you change that to TRUE in your hook along with your other modification. That may change the 'public://' to 'private://' but still just a shot in the dark.

Comment: The "Private" I believe means 'show only to administrators' in this scenario. But I just tried with `$components['file']['extra']['private'] = TRUE;` and no luck. The file upload still gets throw into sites/default/files/webform/upload.

Comment: Worth a shot, did look a little more into this. There is a setting for this in webform I believe. There was an issue posted in the webform issues but it has been resolved. https://www.drupal.org/node/1201084 I will have to load up webform to test and give further instructions.

Comment: @burnsjeremy Yes!! #10 solved a few days ago. I reinstalled webform to my vagrant instance and refreshed (`drush cc all && drush cron`). It now appears in the Field's settings!! Mind moving your comment down into the answer?   https://www.drupal.org/node/1201084#comment-9490409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did a little digging into Webform. There is a setting for this in webform I believe. There was an issue posted in the webform issues but it has been resolved. [Saving file submission to private directory](https://www.drupal.org/node/1201084)

OP already solved but for future onlookers: There are instructions I believe on how to accomplish this in the comments of the issue referenced above, also make sure Webform is up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

Webform itself has an API. You could change the `scheme` from `public` to `private` without hacking the module by implementing [hook_webform_component_info_alter()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_component_info_alter/7).

In a custom module this would look like:

```
function MYMODULE_webform_component_info_alter(&$components) {
  $components['file']['extra']['scheme'] = 'private';
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with the results of using this hook. No go unfortunately. Still get an upvote for introducing me to webforms' hooks.

Comment: Interesting. if I have time I'll try to look at it more, but I'm busy atm.

Comment: Oh please, no worries. Thank you for the initial suggestion.